# Setting default values for custom Maven 2 properties

Tags: maven-2, properties

I have a Maven pom.xml with a plugin that I want to be able to control on the command line. Everything works otherwise fine, except even after searching the net a while I can't figure out how to set a default value for my control property:

```
<plugin>
    ...
    <configuration>
        <param>${myProperty}</param>
    </configuration>
    ...
</plugin>
```

So if I run Maven with

```
mvn -DmyProperty=something ...
```

everything's fine, but I'd like to have a specific value assigned to myProperty also without the `-DmyProperty=...` switch. How can this be done?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can have the property default value defined in `<build>/<properties>` or in a profile like shown below. When you supply the property value on command line with `-DmyProperty=anotherValue` then it will override the definition from the POM. That is, **all** definitions of property values in the POM are set only a *default* value for the properties.

```
<profile>
    ...
    <properties>
        <myProperty>defaultValue</myProperty>            
    </properties>
    ...
       <configuration>
          <param>${myProperty}</param>
       </configuration>
    ...
</profile>
```

Comment: I think profiles might not be the simplest solution in some cases. Check out DavidValeri's answer below.

Comment: @SimonTower, profile is used as an example only. If you use `-D` then property will be overridden whether it was defined in a profile or not.

Answer (score 39):

Taylor L's approach works fine, but you don't need the extra profile.  You can just declare property values in the POM file.

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <!-- Sets the location that Apache Cargo will use to install containers when they are downloaded. 
         Executions of the plug-in should append the container name and version to this path. 
         E.g. apache-tomcat-5.5.20 --> 
    <cargo.container.install.dir>${user.home}/.m2/cargo/containers</cargo.container.install.dir> 
  </properties> 
</project>
```

You can also set properties in your user settings.xml file in the event that you want each user to be able to set their own defaults.  We use this approach to hide credentials that the CI server uses for some plug-ins from regular developers.

Comment: This was simpler than using profiles in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

You could use something like below:

```
<profile>
    <id>default</id>
    <properties>
        <env>default</env>
        <myProperty>someValue</myProperty>            
    </properties>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 6):

@akostadinov's solution works great for common usage... But if the desired property shall be used by reactor component during dependency resolution phase (very early in mvn pom hierarchy processing...) you should use profile "*none activation*" test mechanism to ensure the optional command line provided value is always prioritized regarding the value provided inside pom.xml. And this whatever deep is your pom hierarchy.

To do so, add this kind of profile in your parent pom.xml :

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>my.property</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>!my.property</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <my.property>${an.other.property} or a_static_value</my.property>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Comment: Could you show an example pom where normal `-D` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>default</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
     <plugin>
       <configuration>
        <param>Foo</param>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
    </build>
    ...
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>notdefault</id>
    ...
     <build>
      <plugin>
        <configuration>
            <param>${myProperty}</param>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
     </build>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

That way,

`mvn clean` will use "foo" as your default param. In cases when you need to override, use `mvn -P notdefault -DmyProperty=something`

Comment: Couldn't this be simplified a little by using a activation block to activate nodefault unless no -D property was passed at all.

Comment: @djangofan you're right. I was trying to make my answer a drop in replacement for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I took sal's approach but flatten it a bit.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>default</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
     <plugin>
       <configuration>
        <version>LATEST</version>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now you have 2 options:

1. Using default value: MVN install (all $version will be replaced with LATEST)
2. Using own value: MVN install -P! Default -Dversion=0.9 (all $version will be 0.9)