# maven dynamic version

Tags: maven

I searching a way to dynamise the version of my artifact depending on the profile.

Often I use the -SNAPSHOT suffix when I build for dev or preprod. But the database connection depends on the profile and I never know if the latest SNAPSHOT version was build using the dev or preprod profile.

The idea would be having a version like this

```
<version>1.0${suffix}</version>
```

with ${suffix} =

- "" when building with prod profile
- "-SNAPSHOT" when building with preprod profile
- "-DEV-SNAPSHOT" when building with dev profile

Is there a way of achieving this ?

thanks

edit :

My goal is when I go on jenkins to build my jar, I build the same "tagged" version of my project with the 3 profiles and it deploys 3 differents artifacts.

Actually I tag my project and  go build with the prod profile, then I modify the version to add -SNAPSHOT, commit, move the tag, re build with preprod profile, and then repeat for the dev profile.

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it with Maven. What is your actual goal? Describe that, I will try to help.

Comment: My goal is to know which profile was used, when the artifact was build and installed. I now have to manualy manage my version number every time before I build, depending with which profile I will build.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your answer to @Michael-O comments, i'd recommend to configure the `maven assembly plugin` to create the final name of the artifact according to a system property set on each profile. For example:

```
<build>    
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>create jar according to profile</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}_${profile}</finalName>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

where ${profile} should be a property set to a different value on each profile (for doing that you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899274/setting-default-values-for-custom-maven-2-properties)). I dunno if there's a variable to get the profile being currently used to build, that would be another question :)

Comment: This is not necessary, I would rather use a standard mech: Simply specify a [classifier](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#classifier) for your artifact in the jar plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to reassemble the JAR, I would rather use a standard mech: Simply specify a [classifier](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#classifier) for your artifact in the jar plugin.

Otherwise I would filter a properties in a given properties file and read that in your app. This what I do, e.g. `system.env=prod|test|localdev`.