# Maven properties plugin. Set default value if property isn't found

Tags: maven

Is it possible with properties-maven-plugin to set default value for some property name if it is not found in property file or property file doesn't exists?

EDIT: one possible workaround is to use another profile named for example "set-default-properties" and call it when default settings need. But actually this is not exactly what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899274/setting-default-values-for-custom-maven-2-properties

Comment: Actually a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059138/maven-read-properties-from-file-if-it-exists-and-set-default-properties-otherwi