# How to configure JaCoCo maven plugin from command line

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jacoco

I'm trying to configure JaCoCo maven plugin from command line instead of using `pom.xml`. I have managed to execute `prepare-agent` so far with command:

```
mvn -X -Djacoco.destFile=./coverage/jacoco.exec clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install
```

with output:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.6.201602180812:prepare-agent from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.6.201602180812, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70dea4e]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.6.201602180812:prepare-agent' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) destFile = /src/coverage/jacoco.exec
...
```

which creates `./coverage/jacoco.exec` file and now I'm trying to run `report` stage but I am not able to set properties for this stage. I'm running command:

```
mvn -X -Djacoco.dataFile=./coverage/jacoco.exec -Djacoco.outputDirectory=./jacoco_ut org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report
```

or

```
mvn -X -DdataFile=./coverage/jacoco.exec -DoutputDirectory=./jacoco_ut org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report
```

as in [jacoco:report](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html) there is no `user property` as in [jacoco:prepare-agent](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html).

i have output like:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.6.201602180812:report' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) dataFile = /src/target/jacoco.exec
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /src/target/site/jacoco
[DEBUG]   (f) outputEncoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: project:3.2.0-SNAPSHOT @ /src/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceEncoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

with default values.

Answer (score 7):

#### Update to 0.7.8

The [GitHub issue 322](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/322) has been resolved as of [version 0.7.8](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/releases/tag/v0.7.8) of the `jacoco-maven-plugin`. Starting from this version, you can use the user property `jacoco.dataFile`, so the commands in the question would work as-is.

To force the version on the command line, you should have:

```
mvn -Djacoco.destFile=./coverage/jacoco.exec clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.8:prepare-agent install
```

You can also configure the `jacoco-maven-plugin` inside your POM and specify this version explicitly.

#### Or keep the defaults

Before version 0.7.8, there is no [user property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391502/whats-the-meaning-of-user-property-of-maven-plugin-parameter) for the `dataFile` attribute, so you won't be able to do that. You are correctly overriding the default value when you're invoking

```
mvn -Djacoco.destFile=./coverage/jacoco.exec clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install
```

because [`jacoco.destFile`](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html#destFile) is the name of the user property associated with the `destFile` attribute of the `prepare-agent` goal.

However, there are no user property for the corresponding [`dataFile`](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html#dataFile) attribute of the `report` goal. So your best bet would be to keep the default.

Answer (score 0):

When You can not use property, you can use environment variable.

When I get Jacoco Diff Coverage jacoco:report includes cannot use property.

So I use ${inc_files}

Shell:

```
echo "+++git diff+++"
inc_files=`git diff --name-only master | grep -oP 'com/languoguang/xxclouds/quark.*.java' | xargs | sed 's/.java/.class/g' | xargs | sed -e 's/ /,/g'`;
echo ${inc_files};
echo "---git diff---";

echo "+++maven test jacoco+++";
mvn -B -f pom.xml -Dinc_files=${inc_files} clean test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true;
echo "---maven test jacoco---";
```

pom.xml:

```
<execution>
    <configuration>
        <title>quark-frameworks-coverage-inc</title>
        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-aggregate/jacoco-aggregate-inc/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>${inc_files}</includes>
    </configuration>
    <id>report-aggregate-inc</id>
    <phase>test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

I hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

we use the below code:

```
mvn clean devtestcov:atest -Dactive.devtest -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Djacoco-agent.destfile=target/jacoco.exec
```