# How to run JaCoCo on a Maven project from the command line?

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I want to run JaCoCo from the command line on a Maven project without including JaCoCo configuration into the pom.xml.

How do I configure and invoke JaCoCo from the command line like:

```
$ mvn test <JaCoCo - config params>
```

In essence, I am looking to get a coverage report for a Maven project without having to manually edit its pom.xml. Invoking JaCoCo directly on the Maven project (without invoking the `mvn` command would work to.

Comment: You should at least configure the version into your pom file and afterwards calling is easier from command. I don't understand why you don't want to configure that in your pom file???

Comment: @khmarbaise Because I want to run it on a large number of Maven projects that I do not own, and I am seeking a solution that has low overhead and that does not require configuration changes that may create errors or interfere with the well-functioning of the project in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:prepare-agent  verify org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:report
```

to call jacoco generation directly from command line without any change in your pom file.

You can replace `verify` by `test`

Answer (score 0):

JaCoCo works by instrumenting the virtual machine before tests are run. Normally one configures the Surefire plugin to include some additional args and use a JVM agent, or to rewrite the byte code of the classes to do something equivalent.

I would check this answer: [How to configure JaCoCo maven plugin from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36742797/how-to-configure-jacoco-maven-plugin-from-command-line)

Comment: Does this not require me to actually include the JaCoCo plugin in the pom.xml such that I can invoke the plugin on the command line? If so, is there no option to tell maven on the command line, to include a plugin on-demand? I know that I can configure the Surefire plugin from the command line.

Comment: Take a look at the answers in the linked question!

Comment: I did read that question, in fact I did read it before you recommended it to me. The issue is that I did not recognize the answer to my question in it and I am not sure the use case is similar to mine. To me, that post reads as if the JaCoCo plugin could be set up already in the pom.xml and only *some* configuration is done on-demand from the command line. So, for me, it does not answer the question, can I run JaCoCo without any plugin configuration in the pom.xml whatsoever and will it work on multimodule projects as well? Hope I make sense, I wish I knew more about Maven.