# Maven compiler configuration via built-in properties?

Tags: java, maven, maven-profiles

The [Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) [compile](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) goal indicates (as many of you already know) that I can turn off debug information by setting `<debug>false</debug>`.

```
<project …>
  …
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>production</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <debug>false</debug>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

I note however that the same documentation indicates that the "user property" for this setting is `maven.compiler.debug`. What does it mean that something is a "user property"? Does this mean that I can simply set the `maven.compiler.debug` property to `false` in my profile, and not even mention anything about a plugin, like this?

```
<project …>
  …
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>production</id>
      <properties>
        <maven.compiler.debug>false</maven.compiler.debug>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34659049/5051326):

> "User property" specifies the name of the Maven property that can be used to set a plugin parameter. This allows configuring a plugin from outside the  section. Note that this only works if the parameter is not specified in the  section (see [MNG-4979 - Cannot override configuration parameter from command line](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4979)).

The "User property" on Maven3 can be used on the command line, by specifying
`-Dmaven.compiler.debug=false` or 
in a POM profile like example below, as per your question:

```
<properties> 
  <maven.compiler.debug>false</maven.compiler.debug>
</properties>
```