# Is there a generic way to set -D arguments from within a pom.xml?

Tags: maven, jaxb2-maven-plugin

**tl;dr:** So, is there a way to move the definition of a `-D` system property and to internalise it within the `pom.xml` file?

---

We are currently passing `-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all` from the command line as `mvn clean install -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all` to enable my build to work. I cannot pass the option in the plug-in ([jaxb2-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/) 1.6) since the version we are using doesn't support this and the version that does requires completely changing the configuration and we won't get approval for that.

Trying to set the value of using a tag within `<properties>` like [suggested elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899274/setting-default-values-for-custom-maven-2-properties) by adding under the `<project>` tag:

```
<properties>
    <javax.xml.accessExternalSchema>all</javax.xml.accessExternalSchema>
</properties>
```

but I still get an error (reproduced below) whereas with passing it by the command-line does not.

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
systemId: jar:file:/e:/apache/maven/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/2.2.7/jaxb-xjc-2.2.7.jar!/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/binding.xsd; 
lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 88; schema_reference: 
Failed to read schema document 'xjc.xsd', because 'file' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting default values for custom Maven 2 properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899274/setting-default-values-for-custom-maven-2-properties)

Comment: @Basilevs I tried that answer and I got an error, whereas the plug-in below works so there must be some difference between using a command-line option (ie `-D`) and doing what they suggest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Properties Maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) using the [`set-system-properties` goal](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/set-system-properties-mojo.html) which will set it during the [`initialize` phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>javax.xml.accessExternalSchema</name>
                        <value>all</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the accepted answer here (and many other solutions I found online) did not work for me.
For others having the same problem, the `maven-surefire-plugin` might also offer a solution:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <javax.xml.accessExternalSchema>all</javax.xml.accessExternalSchema>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```